# Import Dynamic ts File Into Project A from Project B

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have two Node based typescript projects A and B. Can I dynamically import a ts file into project A that resides in project B?

It's straight forward to dynamically import a file if it's local to the project e.g.

```
const myImport = await import('./my');
```

But as soon as I try to import a file that exists outside the Project A tsconfig rootDir I get an error:

```
const myImport = await import('c:/projectB/my.ts');
// Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I don't specify the .ts extension I get error:

```
Error: Cannot find module.
```

Using require instead of import results in the same errors:

```
const myImport = require('c://projectB/my.ts');
// Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The typescript code across both projects is commonjs.

I'm trying to create a simple plugin architecture where ProjectA imports a plugin.ts file from ProjectB (with types). In old posts, people suggest copying files or creating symlinks. However, I'd like to publish project A as an NPM package so I don't think this approach will work.

Comment: The path may be correct in the TypeScript file, but is it correct when it gets transpiled to JavaScript?

Comment: The path in the transpiled js looks okay because I'm using an absolute path. const myImport = await Promise.resolve().then(() => require('c:/projectB/my.ts');

Answer (score 0):

Changing the path to point to the transpiled .js file (instead of the .ts) worked. The class can be instantiated successfully. Intellisense works the same as if the class was a local import. Note that my transpiled .js files are in a different folder than my source .ts files (in case that makes a difference).

```
const myImport = await import('c:/projectB/my'); // Note that no file extension is specified.
const myImportClass = new myImport();
myImportClass.myMethod();
```

The example above uses a hard coded absolute path for testing only. This might result in error: File is not under 'rootDir'. Simply work around this by using a variable e.g.

```
const myPath = 'c:/projectB/my';
const myImport = await import(myPath);
```

In my production code I'm using the following dynamic path:

```
const myPath = path.join(process.cwd(), myPath, myFileName);
```